# How to Obtain Reactions Updates via Telegram Bot API

Tags: telegram-bot

Good day,

Is it any chance to obtain via webhooks or long-pooling requests updates related to reactions to messages which was posted by bot? Or at least obtain any reactions updates in channel/group to which a bot was added.

In documentation found API Method:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

But based on how the [response model](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) looks like there are no chance to obtain updates related to reactions.

Did someone has solved such issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situation changed! As of [Telegram Bot API 7.0](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#december-29-2023) your bot can set one reaction per message and it can receive reactions.

First of all, To receive reaction updates you must explicitly specify that your bot want to receive reaction updates in your `getUpdates`/`setWebhook` call.

A call to `getUpdates`/`setWebhook` usually hidden inside a library you use for Telegram Bot API. A library I use has special object BotOptions supplied at bot start. Your library might have something like that.

`getUpdates`/`setWebhook` http requests have parameter `allowed_updates`, that contains  a json-serialized list of all update types you want to receive. Names correspond to Update field names. For example, 'message' to receive new messages. See [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) for a complete list of available update types. Specify an empty list to receive all update types except '*chat_member*', '*message_reaction*', and '*message_reaction_count*' (default). If not specified, the previous setting will be used.

'*message_reaction*' and '*message_reaction_count*' are types we need, so, you have to specify a list of desired update types, including '*message_reaction*' for personal chats and '*message_reaction_count*' for chats with anonymous reactions.

After that you bot will receive updates with reactions.

Answer (score 10):

Response was received in [@BotTalk](https://t.me/BotTalk) community group.

```
Right now (Apr 2022) there is no way to do that.
```

Comment: This makes me sad, considering how fleshed out the rest of the telegram API is.

Comment: Well, it seems that if need be, this could be augmented by regular client API (that is, a regular machine account listens for reaction updates in a group and filters out those interesting).

Very ugly indeed.